Finding persons using MMDetection library that depends on Open MMLAB
I am using MMDetection for Object Detection but I would like to only get the pictures with person labels (I am using the model on the pretrained data COCO)
Does Any one have an Idea ?

Please post your code attempt at solving the problem

def face_detector():
model_name = 'rtmdet_tiny_8xb32-300e_coco.py'
checkpoint = 'rtmdet_tiny_8xb32-300e_coco_20220902_112414-78e30dcc.pth'
inferencer = DetInferencer(model_name, checkpoint, device='cpu') 
result = inferencer("flower.jpg",out_dir='./output')
print(result)

This is my code but it just detects everything in the image  I want to be able to know when a person is detected
